# Load balancing Geonetwork Tomcat + HAProxy

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, haproxy, geonetwork

Recently I configure a Cluster of Two Tomcat (A and B) in one single machine using HAProxy (everything fine). I have deloyed Geonetwork WAR in both Web Servers. I start Tomcat A with no problem, but when start Tomcat B there's an error when its "geonetwork.war" tries to access Lucen indexes, a lock due to write.lock generated (I supose) when Tomcat A started.

The error get is like:

> 2016-11-22 20:47:59,700 ERROR [geonetwork.index] - An error occurred while openning taxonomy readers/writers
>   org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/data/geonetwork/geonetwork_data_agrologia/index/taxonomy/write.lock
>       at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:89)
>       at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:724)
>       at org.apache.lucene.facet.taxonomy.directory.DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.openIndexWriter(DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.java:265)
>       at org.apache.lucene.facet.taxonomy.directory.DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.(DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.java:192)
>       at org.apache.lucene.facet.taxonomy.directory.DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.(DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.java:315)
>       at org.apache.lucene.facet.taxonomy.directory.DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.(DirectoryTaxonomyWriter.java:332)
>       at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.index.TaxonomyIndexTracker.init(TaxonomyIndexTracker.java:46)
>       at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.index.TaxonomyIndexTracker.(TaxonomyIndexTracker.java:40)
>       at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.index.LuceneIndexLanguageTracker.lazyInit(LuceneIndexLanguageTracker.java:75)
>       at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.index.LuceneIndexLanguageTracker.acquire(LuceneIndexLanguageTracker.java:173)
>       at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.SearchManager.getIndexReader(SearchManager.java:1407)
>       at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.SearchManager.getNewIndexReader(SearchManager.java:1411)
>       at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.SearchManager.getDocsChangeDate(SearchManager.java:1066)
>       at org.fao.geonet.kernel.DataManager.init(DataManager.java:240)
>       at org.fao.geonet.Geonetwork.start(Geonetwork.java:378)
>       at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.initAppHandler(JeevesEngine.java:454)
>       at jeeves.server.JeevesEngine.init(JeevesEngine.java:175)
>       at jeeves.server.sources.http.JeevesServlet.init(JeevesServlet.java:82)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5223)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Is there any way to avoid Lucene locks or configure Geonetwork application to permit accessing thos indexes when it is clustered/load balanced?

Comment: Two lucene instances can't use (read and write) the same index without issues (hence the lock). You should change the path used to store data, one copy per tomcat instance.

Comment: I will try this alternative. Thaks

Answer (score 0):

GeoNetwork does not support load balancing out of the box. You will have to combine it with the ["ReadOnly"](https://trac.osgeo.org/geonetwork/wiki/proposals/readonly) configuration and have one master and several slaves.